# DNATing DNS requests that aren't going to a particular server. iptables : No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, firewall

I have some chains that I create in `iptables`

```
iptables -N dns-requests
iptables -N wg0-filter
```

I then create a filter, to pass DNS traffic that are on Port 53.

```
iptables -A wg0-filter -p tcp --dport 53 -j dns-requests
iptables -A wg0-filter -p udp --dport 53 -j dns-requests
```

Then, I have some rules in the `dns-requests` chain:

```
iptables -A dns-requests -d 208.67.220.220 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dns-requests -d 208.67.220.220 -p udp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dns-requests -d 208.67.222.222 -p udp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dns-requests -d 208.67.222.222 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A dns-requests -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination 208.67.220.220:53
iptables -t nat -A dns-requests -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 208.67.222.222:53
```

With the above, I want to do the following:

- DNS requests that are sent to `208.67.220.220` or `208.67.222.222` should pass through
- DNS requests that are **not** sent to `208.67.220.220` or `208.67.222.222` should have `DNAT` applied, so that the `DNS` request goes to `208.67.220.220`

I've tried quite a few different commands, but can't get it to work. The current error I have is:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

When I run :

```
iptables -t nat -A dns-requests -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination 208.67.220.220:53
iptables -t nat -A dns-requests -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 208.67.222.222:53
```

Any ideas how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: FYI your 'missing chain' for dns-requests is because that's a chain in INPUT, not in NAT.  You need to make a new NAT chain called `dns-requests` and the add that into the proper PREROUTING chain in your `iptables`.  see Doug's answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the filtering needs to be done in the nat tables, with extra defined chains created there.

More information about the bigger context would be required, but here is an attempt, which loads without errors but I am unable to test it further:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ cat ask1433946
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.01
#
# ask1433946 Smythies 2022.10.05 Ver:0.01
#       See here:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433946
#
#       run as sudo on s19.
#
#       Note: These rules definately need to be merged with
#       some higher level rules that the OP did not post.

echo "Loading ask1433946 rule set version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
#
# Smythies (for testing)

EXTIF="br0"
EXTIP="192.168.111.136"
DESTU="208.67.220.220"
DESTT="208.67.222.222"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#
# For the actual servers of the question
#
#EXTIF="UNKNOWN"
#EXTIP="UNKNOWN"
#DESTU="208.67.220.220"
#DESTT="208.67.222.222"
#UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#CRITICAL: Enable IP forwarding since it is disabled by default
#
echo Enabling forwarding...
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Clearing any previous configuration
# Be careful here. I can do this on s19, but do not know
# about OP's computer.
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -t nat -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z
# Smythies: While my references do not have it, I think this is needed.
$IPTABLES -t nat -Z

# Define tables in nat.
$IPTABLES -t nat -N wg0-filter
$IPTABLES -t nat -N dns-requests-u
$IPTABLES -t nat -N dns-requests-t

# wgo-filter rules
$IPTABLES -t nat -A wg0-filter -p tcp --dport 53 -j dns-requests-t
$IPTABLES -t nat -A wg0-filter -p udp --dport 53 -j dns-requests-u

# dns-requests rules
$IPTABLES -t nat -A dns-requests-t -d $DESTU -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A dns-requests-t -d $DESTT -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A dns-requests-t -j DNAT --to-destination $DESTT

$IPTABLES -t nat -A dns-requests-u -d $DESTU -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A dns-requests-u -d $DESTT -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A dns-requests-u -j DNAT --to-destination $DESTU

echo ask1433946 rule set version $FWVER done.
```

Which loads fine:

```
$ doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo ./ask1433946
Loading ask1433946 rule set version 0.01..

Enabling forwarding...
  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies..
ask1433946 rule set version 0.01 done.
```

Giving:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 120 packets, 8220 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 36 packets, 5876 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 236 packets, 46387 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 47 packets, 2995 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain wg0-filter (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 dns-requests-t  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
       0        0 dns-requests-u  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53

Chain dns-requests-u (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            208.67.220.220
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            208.67.222.222
       0        0 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:208.67.220.220

Chain dns-requests-t (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            208.67.220.220
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            208.67.222.222
       0        0 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:208.67.222.222
```