# DNS only works when I have a port 53 UDP outbound rule *AND INBOUND* rule

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, firewall

I'm locking down both inbound and outbound ports with

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Then, I allow certain traffic to certain servers

- SSH from my network to the server (inbound)
- HTTP requests on port 8080 from the server to another server (outbound)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <my_ip> --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <server_ip> --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

I noticed some problems with the above rules and doing HTTP requests, so I added

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

For DNS, I then added :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

However, `nslookup` would not work:

```
nslookup google.com
```

What ended up working is also allowing port 53 inbound traffic:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

In total, these are my commands:

```
1. iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <my_ip> --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
2. iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <my_server> --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
3. iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
4. iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
3. iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
4. iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
5. iptables -P INPUT DROP
6. iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

My question is: I wanted to lock down the server as much as possible. I didn't think I'd need to open UDP inbound. I know UDP is stateless etc. but I've generally never needed to open anything inbound to make DNS work, whether on firewalls or my Windows machines.

Am I doing something wrong that I need port 53 inbound?

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make sense that you would need `iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`. When we also consider [your question from yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433946/dnating-dns-requests-that-arent-going-to-a-particular-server-iptables-no-cha), we might need a more complete description of your overall context. Do you still have any lingering rules in the nat PREROUTING chain?

Comment: DNS requires that it has a return path / port for it to work or the system will not receive any answers from the outside DNS servers.  See:  https://simpledns.plus/kb/52/how-do-i-configure-my-firewall-for-dns

Comment: @DougSmythies I ran these commands on a brand new installation